# Android OS - Stop user from closing app or using any OS functionality

Tags: android, security

My team is trying to build an Android application for a tablet that will be dedicated for this sole purpose. One of the requirements is that the application is the only thing running on the device (at least from the user's point of view). The user should not be able to close it or use any other functionality from the OS (settings, other apps, etc.).

We have been doing some research and so far have not found anything. Is this we are trying to do even possible ? Does anybody have any idea how we could approach this ? Maybe blocking the buttons ?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea, a terrible device, and a terrible company. Do you work at apple?

Comment: This is the responsibility of whoever is making the device, not your responsibility.

Comment: Why would any one want to use this app? Maybe its for some internal use that you need this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but would be ugly in the long run without a custom built rom (http://xda-developers.com has instructions on how to do this), I wouldn't know where to start code wise - but there are a couple of applications which portray this kind of functionality - TodlerLock is one such app - its designed to stop todlers from from doing anything on the device, whilst the application keeps them entertained. It appears to intercept all button presses and acts as a home application to do this for the home button.

Then there are the programs like estrongs security manager that allows a user to set a password for some or all applications and basically stops the application being run without the password (it appears to intercept the intents and opens the security manager requesting the password first, if it fails it finishes the intent) - this maybe a much easier option to use something like this - you could set a password for most things, including settings and the security application itself, everything bar your application. This will stop the user doing anything you dont want them doing without the password.

You would have to set up the device for the user before hand though, as any home screen intercepter application can be changed but the user - so you would have to set the default, then lock access to the settings so the user can't change this action.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way of doing this to have your own custom version of Android built only for you. Get the android source, remove what ever you don't want and build it. I am not sure if you would ever want not to close it but you can make sure they can't install anything else on your ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about this, but, intercept the home intent and write your own custom home?

It sounds a lot simpler than writing your own custom rom.

Comment: You can write your own custom home screen, but you can't force the user to use it.  The user would still be able to switch back to the default home screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without OS changes.  You cannot override the home button.